# How can I remove a lib file from "Commandline" in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

My C++ VisualStudio2017 project is giving me the following error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: mcs-project, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>chain.cpp
1>crmsd.cpp
1>eef1.cpp
1>leaf.cpp
1>Matrix.hpp
1>node.cpp
1>pairtree.cpp
1>pdb.cpp
1>rss.cpp
1>simulation.cpp
1>slist.cpp
1>spheres.cpp
1>Vector.hpp
1>Generating Code...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'matplot.lib'
1>Done building project "mcs-project.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: mcs-unit-test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>pch.cpp
2>test__Vector.cpp
2>test__Vector.cpp(18): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
2>gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_reverse_trivially_swappable_4 referenced in function "void __cdecl std::_Reverse_unchecked1<enum testing::internal::edit_distance::EditType *>(enum testing::internal::edit_distance::EditType * const,enum testing::internal::edit_distance::EditType * const,struct std::integral_constant<unsigned __int64,4>)" (??$_Reverse_unchecked1@PEAW4EditType@edit_distance@internal@testing@@@std@@YAXQEAW4EditType@edit_distance@internal@testing@@0U?$integral_constant@_K$03@0@@Z)
2>C:\git\MCS\x64\Debug\mcs-unit-test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "mcs-unit-test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

After intense searching, I found that the Properties -> Linker -> Commandline contains the following text:

```
/OUT:"C:\git\MCS\x64\Debug\mcs-project.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT 
/PDB:"C:\git\MCS\x64\Debug\mcs-project.pdb" 
/DYNAMICBASE "matplot.lib" "nodesoup.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" 
"comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" 
"odbccp32.lib" 
/DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\git\MCS\x64\Debug\mcs-project.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\mcs-project.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\git\MCS\external_libs\Matplot++ 1.2.0\lib\Debug" /TLBID:1
```

[image]

I need to remove `matplot.lib` from the project.

However, I cannot edit this command-line arguments.

How can I remove `matplot.lib`?

---

N.B. The "Additional Dependency" contains nothing

[image]

Comment: "*However, I cannot edit this command-line arguments*"- why not?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, from where should I edit this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `Additional Dependencies` option is blank.

Comment: Didn't you make this solution? How did you add it? Try PropertySheets.

Comment: @TheNomad, Yes, I made this. However, most probably I interited the properties.

Comment: @TheNomad, How can I edit property sheets?

Comment: View -> Other Windows -> Property Manager. You can dock it on the workspace panel where you have your Solution Explorer and regular Properties. I can't guarantee that what you need is there, but I heard some defaults (including some preprocessors definitions might be there). Check all the ones under Debug x64. If your solution has multiple projects, you might want to check other ones as well including the libs in the regular properties. Those are the only ideas I can think of at the moment. Personally, I use Property Sheets for custom solution macros such as directory paths and such.

Comment: Search the code for `#pragma comment(lib, "matplot.lib")` as well. That's another way of adding libraries to the linker.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, How can I stop the automatic inheritance of properties?

Comment: @user366312 I am not sure what you are asking. If you find the line of code in your program that I mentioned and don't wish that library to be linked then delete that line.

Comment: Look in the vcxproj file (it's just xml). Remove the reference from there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, PropertySheets had that file. I removed that. Now, it is all ok.

Comment: @ChrisMM, `vcxproj` didn't have any mention of that file.

Comment: It's where you saved your project. If you can't find it, open the solution (*.sln) file in Notepad++ or a similar text editor and see where the project file is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the linker pragma won't end up in the linker command line, the linker picks it up directly from the object files

Comment: Can you please expand the list of References that your project is using? It's in *Solution Explorer* under the project name. Expand that, sshot it and post the picture.